# Is it possible to derive class attribute in the same time as the class?

Tags: c++, derived

I'm asking to do a Vec which heritates from a ABR. This ABR got 3 pointers as attribute with ABR type. i'd like to know if those pointers'type can become Vec while derivating into Vec without template parameters?

here's somme code to picture it:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    Base* x;
public:
    Base(): x(nullptr){}
    Base* getVal() {return x;}
};

class Derived: public Base
{
private:
    int y;
public:
    Derived():Base(), y(-1) {}
    Derived(int Y): y(Y){}

    Derived* getVal() {return x;}
    void setVal(Derived *ptr){this->x = ptr;}
};

int main()
{
    Derived D(5), c(7),*ptrToC=&c;
    D.setVal(ptrToC);
    D.getVal();
}
```

This code will return an error at "D.getVal()" because x is still a Base pointer so is it possible to make it have the same type as the class he is in?

Comment: Isn't Polymorphism (originated from Hellenic many forms) helping here?

Comment: Inheritance without virtual functions is dubious to say the least. Why do you need `Base` at all?

Answer (score 0):

The only option to do this is templates. As a way - [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) idiom:

```
template <class T>
class Base
{
protected:
   Base* x;
public:
   Base() : x(nullptr) {}
   T* getVal() { return dynamic_cast<T*>(x); }

   virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
private:
   int y;
public:
   Derived() :Base(), y(-1) {}
   Derived(int Y) : y(Y) {}

   void setVal(Derived *ptr) { this->x = ptr; }
};

int main()
{
   Derived D(5), c(7), *ptrToC = &c;
   D.setVal(ptrToC);
   D.getVal();
}
```

Also note that there is no polymorphism in your code. You need to create a table of virtual functions for `Base` by adding at least one virtual method (f.e. destructor). unless of course you want to cast Base to Derived

Answer (score 0):

You have to ways here, either simple polymorphism or templates.

Polymorphism way:

In a `Derived` object, the `x` member while being declared as a `Base *` will indeed point only to `Derived` objects, because its value can only be set to a `Derived *`. So it is safe to cast it in `getVal`:

```
...
Derived* getVal() {return static_cast<Derived *>(x);}
...
```

Template way.

You could use the [curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) here:

```
template<class T>
class Base
{
protected:
    T* x;
public:
    Base(): x(nullptr){}
    T* getVal() {return x;}
};

class Derived: public Base<Derived> {
private:
    int y;
public:
    Derived():Base(), y(-1) {}
    Derived(int Y): y(Y){}

    Derived* getVal() {return x;}
    void setVal(Derived *ptr){this->x = ptr;}
};
```

Comment: I did not fully understand what the author wants, but it seems he want to cast  Base  to Derived . It will not work in your case. Because 'dynamic_cast': 'Base<Derived>' is not a polymorphic type

Comment: @DmytroDadyka there's no `dynamic_cast` in this answer

Comment: @Caleth, It’s not clear from the author’s question whether he wants to use dynamic typing. It seemed to me what he wanted. Otherwise, it is not clear why he needs a pointer to the base class.